# d3 bar chart overflow

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have the following code which creates a bar chart on a time scale in d3, however the last bar always goes out of the axis. I am not sure what is the problem and how to fix it, I already spent hours looking at it.
What am I doing wrong?
[image]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.axis text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m").parse;

var margin = {top: 20, right: 100, bottom: 20, left: 100},
    outerWidth = 1000;
    innerWidth = outerWidth - margin.left - margin.right; //800
    outerHeight = 300;
    innerHeight = outerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; //300

var xScale = d3.time.scale()
    .range([0, innerWidth])
    .nice(d3.time.week);

var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([innerHeight,0]);


var mainContainer = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", outerWidth)
        .attr("height", outerHeight);

var mainGroup = mainContainer.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


d3.csv("bar-data.csv", function(error, data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.value = +d.value;
    });

//xScale.domain([new Date(parseDate("2013-01")), new Date(parseDate("2017-12"))]);
xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
yScale.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; })]);

mainGroup.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr('transform','translate(0,'+innerHeight+')')
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(xScale).orient("bottom"));
mainGroup.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(yScale).orient("left"));

mainGroup.selectAll("bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .style("fill", "rgb(28, 175, 154)")
      .attr("x", function(d) {return xScale(new Date(d.date));})
      .attr("width", (innerWidth/data.length))
      .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return innerHeight - yScale(d.value); });

});

</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 Time based scales overflowing axis](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39811367/d3-time-based-scales-overflowing-axis)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to create a workaround by increasing the domain with 1 unit, therefore the axis will increase a tiny bit.

Comment: How did you achieve this?